# web3.py, how to sign transaction with impersonate account of Ganache-Cli

Tags: web3.py, ganache, blockchain-fork

After forking mainnet with Ganache-cli and impersonating account I don't own, I find a problem in web3.py.

I don't have the private key to sign the transaction.

```py
tx_signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx_build, private_key)
```

However, when it comes to Etherjs and Hardhat, I don't have the issue. I have the impersonated public address and it's enough to get the transaction done, under the forking environment.

I can develop in JS and Python, but Python is preferred as it's of high efficiency.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to have the private key to sign a spoofed transaction.

You can use eth_sendTransaction API to send an unsigned transaction Ganache over HTTP. Ganache node does not check the signature of these transactions.

[You can find some examples and details here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary/eth_defi.ganache.fork_network.html#eth_defi.ganache.fork_network), though those might not directly to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! you are a fu*king legend!!! ```w3.eth.sendTransaction(tx_build)``` , add from: impersonated address to the tx_build, done!

Comment: Is it possible to send unsigned raw transaction?

Comment: No. You need to sign it with using `Localccount`.